# Can a table field be founded and then updated with a value in mvc Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

yeah so the question is pretty simple: Can a table field be found using and ID and then updated with a value in mvc Controller?

And before anyone gets downvote crazy... I have no example because I don't know how to do this... it's not a home work question or any other things that you down vote on this site. It's a simple question that I need an answer and a example.

I now you can use the .find to and pass the ID... to a dataset but there is nothing I can find that shows you how to edit the values in the table once you find it.

So this part I get, This will allow me to find the the id with in the dataset.

```
        TEST_DS tEST_DS = db.TEST_DS.Find(id);
        if (tEST_DS == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
```

Also I know that you see a call to the database like This

db.TEST_TABLE.Add(TEST_DS);

I don't see an option for edit or anything like that.

The task is to update a table field, The field is a status field so when the user makes a change on the mvc create form. When they create a record I want to mark a different table's status field with a number that represents a record was created.

Did a search did not see anything.. thanks may be something mvc can't do because of it's limitations or something.

If you do answer question I will need an example of a link to an example on how to do it. Thanks!!

Comment: There are LOTS of ways of doing this.  jQuery, Knockout and probably hundreds of other frameworks allow you to manually or automatically bind value in javascript to html elements.  At some point all of those frameworks will make an Ajax call to retrieve the information.  So yes it can be done, but you'll need to do research on how you want to accomplish it.  (be careful, asking for which framework to use is off topic for SO).

Comment: Hi Erik Philips, thanks for the heads up... maybe I should not ask this question here on Staackoverflow because I sure don'tt want downvotes... these guys here are tuff on people..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work some  I will post It there for others as they might have the same issues when dealing that mvc limitations and such.

So the answer is to simply have your data table in the dbcontext that you need to edit...

The code would not post.. it asking for 4 spaces and I gave it 4 spaces and it did not work so I added a picture.

See Code[Answer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2mPD.png)